# When I close The Application ... And Open The Notification ... I Click On Back on TestActicty it close the app and dont back to main Actitvty

Tags: java, android

When I Close the Application and Open The Notification It Open TestActicty .. but when I click on back it close the app ... no back to main Activity .. and I need it back to `MainActivity`

```
Intent in=new Intent(this,TestActicity.class);
        PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,1,in,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Intent BroadCast=new Intent(this, TestActicity.class);
        BroadCast.putExtra("Link","Hello");
        PendingIntent BpendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,BroadCast,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification notfy=new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), App.CHANNEL_1_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Test")
                .setContentText("Walaaaaaa")
                .setContentIntent(p)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"toast",BpendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Replay",p)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(5,notfy);
```

Comment: Keep the title short, and add description  in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a BaseActivity.java class extending AppCompatActivity
- This should be extended by TestActivity as well as MainActivity
- Implement onBackPressed() in BaseActivity and get if this activity is the last activity in the stack and if yes then it should be MainActivity, otherwise launch MainActivity as below code,
  So, to determine if an activity is the last one:
- request android.permission.GET_TASKS permissions in the manifest.
- Use the following code:

  ```
  ActivityManager mngr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
  List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = mngr.getRunningTasks(10);
  if(taskList.get(0).numActivities == 1 &&
          !taskList.get(0).topActivity.getClassName().equals(MainActivity.getClass().getName()))
  {
      Log.i(TAG, "Need to launch MainActivity");
      Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
  }
  ```